# CRTP compiling error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr, crtp

The following will compile with GCC 5.2 but not with Visual Studio 2015.

```
template <typename Derived>
struct CRTP {
    static constexpr int num = Derived::value + 1;
};

struct A : CRTP<A> {
    static constexpr int value = 5;
};
```

It complains that `A` does not have a member named `value`.
How to fix the code so that it compiles on both compilers?  Or is it illegal altogether?

Comment: It also fails to compile on clang.

Comment: Is it illegal syntax, and GCC simply fluked out?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like it should be illegal, otherwise you could have `num = Derived::value` and `value = CRTP<V>::num`

Comment: But on GCC it compiles and also when running my program, all outputs are as expected, i.e. no undefined behaviour.

Comment: `Derived=A` is incomplete, so I doubt this is valid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try making it a constexpr function instead. The way you have it setup now attempts to access an incomplete type.
Since a templated member function will only be initialized upon first being used, type `A` will be fully defined by that point.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived>
struct CRTP {
    static constexpr int num() { return  Derived::value + 1; }
};

struct A : CRTP<A> {
    static constexpr int value = 5;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << A::num();
    return 0;
}
```

See it live [here](http://ideone.com/zbradM)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
template <typename Derived>
struct CRTP {
    static constexpr int num = Derived::value + 1;
                               ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
};
```

At the time of the instantiation of `CRTP<A>`, `A` isn't a complete class yet, so you can't actually access static members of it.

One workaround is to pass in `num` as a separate template argument:

```
template <typename Derived, int N>
struct CRTP {
    static constexpr int num = N;
};

struct A : CRTP<A, 5> {

};
```

Comment: Why does the initializer of `CRTP<Derived>::num` need to be instantiated at the time `CRTP<Derived>` is instantiated? Can you provide a reference to the standard?

Comment: What I found is `[temp.inst] p9`: "The implicit instantiation of a class template does not cause any static data members of that class to be
implicitly instantiated".

Comment: @HighCommander4 That has to do with the definition of the member - the declaration still has to be parsed and valid, which it is not in the OP's example as `Derived` is as yet incomplete.