# Should a definition inside template class be instantiated if it is not used?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    static constexpr T obj {};

    static constexpr bool noexcept_copy = noexcept( T{obj} );
    static void UsesCopy() { T{obj}; }

    static constexpr int  C = 1;
};

struct NoCopy
{
    constexpr NoCopy() = default;
    NoCopy(const NoCopy&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    return A<NoCopy>::C;
}
```

The code above is successfully compiled by GCC, but Clang gives a compilation error:

```
tmp.cpp:6:57: error: call to deleted constructor of 'NoCopy'
        static constexpr bool noexcept_copy = noexcept( T{obj} );
                                                        ^~~~~~
tmp.cpp:20:16: note: in instantiation of template class 'A<NoCopy>' requested here
        return A<NoCopy>::C;
               ^
tmp.cpp:15:9: note: 'NoCopy' has been explicitly marked deleted here
        NoCopy(const NoCopy&) = delete;
        ^
1 error generated.
```

The `A::UsesCopy` function uses copy constructor as well, but the compiler does not complain about the usage of deleted function there. What is the difference between `UsesCopy` function and `noexcept_copy` constexpr? Both use copy constructor of `NoCopy` class and both are not used but the constexpr definition produces a compilation error, the function definition does not.

**PS.** Clang compiles the code above with `-std=c++17` or `-std=c++2a`, but not with `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`.

Comment: Isn't that what SFINAE is for?

Comment: clang is correct here - even if not used *in the end* you DO use a call to the c-tor on the instantiated type - that which you deleted - Solution: use SFINAE

Comment: `A::UsesCopy` would produce error (which depends of `T`) only when instantiated, which is not the case here.

Comment: The error occurs only with Clang compilation against C++2a, and not against C++17: https://wandbox.org/permlink/11Zw3rbSNDM9ZYZZ.

Comment: [temp.spec#temp.inst-10](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.inst-10) *"An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member class, a static data member of a class template, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement ([stmt.if]), unless such instantiation is required."*

Comment: Unsure if `constexpr` makes instantiation required though.

Comment: I can't reproduce this compilation error. I only see something about `NoCopy` not being a literal type (which is easily fixable, by adding a `constexpr` default constructor).

Comment: For me it work only in C++17, but not C++14. I suspect the fact that constexpr variables are now inline

Comment: @Brian, it doesn't compile with `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`, but compile with `-std=c++17` or `-std=c++2a`. PS I added `constexpr` default constructor.

Comment: The definition of static data members and non-deleted member functions should not be instantiated ([\[temp.inst\]/(2.1)](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#2)). But in this particular snippet, the in-class initialization of a static constexpr data member is not a definition prior to C++17. I'd say the behavior is underspecified in this case. (Though it doesn't affect `static constexpr bool` members in C++17 and later, it still matters for `static const bool` members that are not `constexpr`.)

Comment: This seems to be related to [a number of core issues](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2335) on the subject of just what happens while instantiating a class template and its `constexpr` members.

Comment: Constructor does not have any return type. Then how `constexpr NoCopy() = default;` this line is compiled in gcc ?

Comment: @KamalPancholi, `constexpr` is not a type. It is a keyword that means that this constructor can be used in constant expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct approach to deal with this issue is similar to what is details in [this pre-C++17 answer to a question about the order of initialization of static constexpr templated data members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37818272/53538).

**TL;DR** - yes GCC, got it right, Clang tries to resolve the copy c'tor even though it is not allowed.

To summarize:

## C++14

In p9.4.2.3 - Static data members, we have:

> [...] A `static` data member of literal type can be declared in the
>   class definition with the `constexpr` specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer*
>   in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression. [...] The member shall still be defined
>   in a namespace scope if it is odr-used in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an *initializer*.

So the declaration of `static constexpr` data member is just a declaration and is not a definition - even though it has an *initializer*. A definition is required to cause initialization, and none is provided in the original OP code.

To drive home the point, we have the previously quoted p14.7.1 - Templates - Implicit Instantiation (emphasis mine):

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the
>   declarations, **but not of the definitions**, default arguments, or exception-specifications of the class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, **static data members** and member template

GCC correctly does not initialize `noexcept_copy` as there is no definition for it, only a decleration - it is never "defined in a namespace scope", as required by p9.4.2.3.

## C++17

So what changed? Well, as far as I can tell - nothing major, but there were some changes around how static data members are defined, in C++17, by adopting [P0389R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r2.pdf) whose purpose - as far as I understand - it so introduce "inline variables" which can be declared simply and then odr-used in multiple translation units with the same storage, i.e. there's only one instance of the variable initialized with the *initializer* in the declaration - this is similar to "static field initialization" in other languages such as Java and makes it easier to have singleton eager initialization.

Here's from the spec:

> A declaration is a definition unless [...] it declares a non­-inline static data member in a class definition.

So we explicitly specify that `inline` static data member's declaration **is** a definition. No need for an external definition out of the class scope. This certainly makes it easier for programmers.

But what `inline` has to do with `constexpr`? The adoption of the proposal also resulted in this specification in p10.1.5.1:

> A function or static data member declared with the `constexpr` specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable.

So this change actually makes it pretty explicit that the declaration of `static constexpr bool noexcept_copy` is also a definition - which we mustn't instantiate in case of an implicit template instantiation.

I'm guessing this is a strong enough signal for Clang developers to not initialize the `static constexpr` data members.

BTW, the example in C++17 Appendix D p.1 explains this rather explicitly:

```cpp
struct A {
  static constexpr int n = 5; // definition (declaration in C++ 2014)
};
constexpr int A::n; // redundant declaration (definition in C++ 2014)
```

From this example we learn that, in C++ 2014 a declaration of a `static constexpr` was not a definition, and in order for the initialization to take place, you must have a definition in a namespace scope.

So Clang is wrong outputing an error in their C++14 implementation because in the OP code, not only is it wrong to implicitly instantiate the template class static data member - there isn't even a definition for it so it shouldn't have been instantiated even if it wasn't a template class.

Answer (score -1):

I think this problem is referred by the following standard lines on template :

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function
>   template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member
>   function, a member class, a static data member of a class template, or
>   a substatement of a constexpr if statement, unless such instantiation
>   is required.

So the **Clang** compiler do the right things. **GCC** in this case erronously don't give you an error.

> ***PS. Clang compiles the code above with -std=c++17 or -std=c++2a, but
>   not with -std=c++11 or -std=c++14.***

In fact with the c++17 there was a change in the template standard.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question, `noexcept_copy` is a static data member, so if anything those lines seem to suggest that GCC is correct. The question, as pointed out in the comments, is whether using `constexpr` in a static data member makes it "required" or not. If there were changes in C++17 it may be useful to know what are the relevant changes that make the difference here.